# How to plot a list of vectors with different lengths?

Tags: r, list, vector, plot

I have a list with 9 different vectors inside. And I want plot them (dot-line) in one figure with different colors by their names.  How to do that in R language?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using a made up example:

```
# example data:
dat <- list(a=1:5,b=2:7,c=3:10)
# get plotting:
plot(unlist(dat),type="n",xlim=c(1,max(sapply(dat,length))))
mapply(lines,dat,col=seq_along(dat),lty=2)
legend("topleft",names(dat),lty=2,col=seq_along(dat))
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

No question would be complete without a ggplot answer.

```
dat <- list(a=1:5,b=2:7,c=3:10)
dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) cbind(x = seq_along(x), y = x))

list.names <- names(dat)
lns <- sapply(dat, nrow)
dat <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", dat))
dat$group <- rep(list.names, lns)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_line(linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]

To plot each line in a separate plot, use

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_line(linetype = "dotted") +
    facet_wrap(~ group)
```

Comment: `dat$group <- rep(names(dat), lns)` would make sure the names match in your groups.

Comment: can you have each group in it's own plot window. like a facet plot.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Your dat is now three times the size of the original. If you must ggplot, do it right. Put the indexing, grouping, etc inside your ggplot.

Comment: @hplotusx can you explain a bit? I'm not sure I understand.