# Couple of issues with plotting multiple data series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot four different series of vectors:

**1) adm**
  7  9 46 11 52 29 25 62

**2) pat**
  35 29 24 19 22 21 42 23 34 12 28 17 11 15 16 14 27 20  8 38 10 10 14 22
 22 23 24 24 24

**3) nur**
  41 49 42 59 58 23 35 31 20 44 56 29 57 50 33 46 28 17 15 17 28 44 46 49
 50 57 58

**4) med**
  23 51 44 54 26 15 33 41 34 42 39

I tried the following to plot the multiple data series on the same plot:

```
plot(pat,type="l",xlab="Degree",ylab="Count",col="blue4")
par(new=T)
plot(adm,type="l",xlab="Degree",ylab="Count",col="red4")
par(new=T)
plot(med,type="l",xlab="Degree",ylab="Count",col="green4")
par(new=T)
plot(nur,type="l",xlab="Degree",ylab="Count",col="black")
par(new=F)
```

and I got this...
[image]

The two things I need help with are:

1) Create a legend for the graph matching each line with its data source.

2) Fix the overlapping labels in the plot (by that I mean the values on x and y axis)

Comment: See here for some assistance: [how to plot a list of vectors with different lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179856/how-to-plot-a-list-of-vectors-with-different-lengths). Collecting your vectors into a `list` first will help. Both a base R and a ggplot solution are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit easier if you store your values in a list

```
dd<-list(
  adm=c(7,9,46,11,52,29,25,62),           
  pat=c(35,29,24,19,22,21,42,23,34,12,28,17,11,15,16,
        14,27,20,8,38,10,10,14,22,22,23,24,24,24),
  nur=c(41,49,42,59,58,23,35,31,20,44,56,29,57,50,33,
        46,28,17,15,17,28,44,46,49,50,57,58),
  med =c(23,51,44,54,26,15,33,41,34,42,39)
)

ylim=c(0, max(sapply(dd, range)))
xlim=c(0, max(sapply(dd, length)))    
cols<-c("blue4","red4","green4","black")

plot(dd[[1]], xlab="Degree", ylab="Count", col=cols[1], type="l", xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
for(i in 2:4) {
    lines(dd[[i]], col=cols[i])
}
legend(x=25,50, names(dd), col=cols, lty=1)
```

[image]

As a general rule, you only ever call `plot` once; then if you need to add data, it's better to use `points()` or `lines()` which do not re-draw the axes.

Libraries like `lattice` tend to make grouped plots easier

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(values~idx, transform(stack(dd), idx=ave(values, ind, FUN=seq_along)), 
    group=ind, auto.key=list(lines=T, points=F, columns=2), type="l")
```

[image]