# Different length for x,y in plot

Tags: r, plot

How do I actually plot a graph with a different range of x and y-axis?
For example

```
plot (0:30, 10:-10, type="l", col="green")
```

there is a different range for x and y when I run it, it will come out with some errors.

Comment: It's not the range that's the problem - 0:30 has 31 elements, 10:-10 has 21  (check with `length(10:-10)`).  R doesn't know what you want to plot the 22nd element of 0:30 against.  `plot (0:30, 20:-10, type="l", col="green")` would work fine, as both `x` and `y` are the same length

Comment: If you could describe what you expect the drawn coordinates to be, maybe there is a way to do that. Is it a single line drawn vom (0,10) to (30, -10) you want to be drawn?

Comment: Yes I want to draw a line from (0,10) to (30,-10).  Is there any ways to do it?

Comment: As @Bernhard implies try: `plot (c(0, 30), c(10,-10), type="l", col="green") `

Comment: [The answer you're looking for is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179856/how-to-plot-a-list-of-vectors-with-different-lengths)